# Kivy: problem with widget id assign by variable

Tags: kivy

I have data from MySQL and use the data to show labels text.

My problem is:

This code `self.ids.product_name.text = name` is not changing label text

My try:

First, I try to print the variable name, and on the console, the data is correct.

Second, I try to set it with a string, which is correct, but when I use assign with a variable, there is no show on the label.

Third, I try to use specific ID to get data from mysql `id = 1` label text is change. If I use id from `id = value` which is I receive from other class. Label is not change. I print `value` is show correct id on terminal. Why I use `value` is incorrect?

```
[WARNING] Deprecated property "<BooleanProperty name=allow_stretch>" of object "<kivy.uix.image.Image object at 0x1232f44b0>" was accessed, it will be removed in a future version
[WARNING] Deprecated property "<BooleanProperty name=keep_ratio>" of object "<kivy.uix.image.Image object at 0x1232f44b0>" was accessed, it will be removed in a future version
[INFO   ] [Base        ] Start application main loop
[INFO   ] [GL          ] Unpack subimage support is available
selection removed for MARVEL’S SPIDER-MAN 2
selection removed for MARVEL’S SPIDER-MAN 2
selection removed for Call of Duty: Modern Warfare III
selection removed for Elden Ring
selection removed for God of War Ragnarök
2023-12-09 18:31:13.562 Python[54036:3570437] WARNING: Secure coding is not enabled for restorable state! Enable secure coding by implementing NSApplicationDelegate.applicationSupportsSecureRestorableState: and returning YES.
selection changed to Elden Ring
Recieve ID:  3 <------ ID is receieve
Fetched name: Elden Ring <------- name is match with id. It is correct.
[INFO   ] [Base        ] Leaving application in progress...
```

```
from kivy.uix.button import Button
from kivy.uix.image import Image
from kivy.uix.label import Label
from kivy.graphics import Color, Rectangle
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.core.window import Window
from kivy.uix.screenmanager import Screen
import database_handler
from kivy.lang import Builder
from kivy.uix.relativelayout import RelativeLayout
from kivy.uix.gridlayout import GridLayout
from kivy.clock import Clock
from globalstate import GlobalState

Builder.load_file('product.kv')

class ProductDetailScreen(Screen):
    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        super(ProductDetailScreen, self).__init__(**kwargs)
        #Clock.schedule_once(self.get_value)

    def on_enter(self, *args):
        GlobalState.is_user_authenticated = True
        # Check user authentication status
        if not GlobalState.is_user_authenticated:
            # If not authenticated, go to the login screen
            self.manager.current = 'home'
            return

class ProductDetail(RelativeLayout):
    def __init__(self, **kw):
        super().__init__(**kw)
        #Clock.schedule_once(self.get_value)

    def get_value(self, id, *args):

        print("Recieve ID: ", id)
        result_data = database_handler.load_product_detail(id)

        for x in result_data:
            name = x[1]

        # Update the label text with the fetched data
        print("Fetched name:", name)

        self.ids.product_name.text = name <----- This code is not change Label text
        #self.ids.root.product_name.text = name
        #self.ids.product_image.source = str(image)
        #self.ids.product_description.text = description
        

        

class MainApp(App):
    def build(self):
        sm = Screen()
        return sm

if __name__ == '__main__':
    MainApp().run()
```

Kv language

```
<ProductDetailScreen>:
    ProductDetail:

<ProductDetail>:
    description: ''
    image: ''
    canvas:
        Color:
            rgba: 0.898039, 0.898039, 0.909804, 1
        Rectangle:
            pos: self.pos
            size: self.size
        
    Label:
        id: product_name
        text: 'product name'
        font_family: 'Roboto'
        font_size: 45
        color: 0.482353, 0.552941, 0.576471, 1
        size_hint: (0.379688, 0.0541667)
        pos_hint: {'x':0.0484375, 'y':0.88125}
        text_size: 300, None

        Label:
            id: product_description
            text: root.description
            font_family: 'Roboto'
            font_size: 35
            color: 0.482353, 0.552941, 0.576471, 1
            size_hint: (0.379688, 0.0541667)
            pos_hint: {'x':0.0640625, 'y':0.423958}
            text_size: 300, None

    Image:
        id: product_image
        source: root.image
        allow_stretch: True
        pos_hint: {'x':0.178125, 'y':0.50625}
        size_hint: (0.671875, 0.322917)
```

This is class that I use to send value

```
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.uix.screenmanager import Screen
from globalstate import GlobalState
from kivy.lang import Builder
from kivy.uix.recycleview import RecycleView
from kivy.uix.gridlayout import GridLayout
from kivy.clock import Clock
import database_handler
from kivy.uix.recycleview.views import RecycleDataViewBehavior
from kivy.properties import BooleanProperty
from kivy.uix.recyclegridlayout import RecycleGridLayout
from kivy.uix.behaviors import FocusBehavior
from kivy.uix.recycleview.layout import LayoutSelectionBehavior
from product import ProductDetail

Builder.load_file('productlistview.kv')

class ProductListViewMain(Screen):
    def __init__(self, **kw):
        super(ProductListViewMain, self).__init__(**kw)

    def on_enter(self, *args):
        GlobalState.is_user_authenticated = True
        # Check user authentication status
        if not GlobalState.is_user_authenticated:
            # If not authenticated, go to the login screen
            self.manager.current = 'home'
            return
        
class SearchProduct(GridLayout):
    pass

class RV(RecycleView):
    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        super(RV, self).__init__(**kwargs)
        Clock.schedule_once(self.load_product)
        
    def load_product(self, *args):
        
        load_data = database_handler.load_product_list()
        if load_data:
            self.data = [{'id': str(x[0]),'name': str(x[1]), 'price': 'A${}'.format(str(x[4])), 'image': str(x[5])} for x in load_data]
        else:
            print("Result is none.")

class SelectableRecycleGridLayout(FocusBehavior, LayoutSelectionBehavior,RecycleGridLayout):
    pass

class ProductList(RecycleDataViewBehavior, GridLayout):
    ''' Add selection support to the Label '''
    index = None
    selected = BooleanProperty(False)
    selectable = BooleanProperty(True)

    def refresh_view_attrs(self, rv, index, data):
        ''' Catch and handle the view changes '''
        self.index = index
        return super(ProductList, self).refresh_view_attrs(
            rv, index, data)

    def on_touch_down(self, touch):
        ''' Add selection on touch down '''
        if super(ProductList, self).on_touch_down(touch):       
            return True
        if self.collide_point(*touch.pos) and self.selectable:
            return self.parent.select_with_touch(self.index, touch)

    def apply_selection(self, rv, index, is_selected):
        ''' Respond to the selection of items in the view. '''
        self.selected = is_selected
        if is_selected:
            id = rv.data[index]['id']
            print("selection changed to {0}".format(rv.data[index]['name']))

            # Switch to the 'product_detail' screen
            App.get_running_app().root.current = 'product_detail'   
            ProductDetail.get_value(self, id)
        else:
            print("selection removed for {0}".format(rv.data[index]['name']))

      
class ProductListViewApp(App):
    def build(self):
        sm = Screen()
        return sm
    
if __name__ == '__main__':
    ProductListViewApp().run()
```

Answer (score 0):

I can't test your code, because I don't have all the modules, so I'm honestly not sure any of these options will work for you. Ideally someone more experienced will answer this, but here are a few thoughts I have:

1. In the `ProductList` class in the `apply_selection()` method, you could try replacing `ProductDetail.get_value(self, id)` with `ProductDetail.get_value(ProductDetail, id)`. Possibly python is using `ProductList` class as the `self` instead of `ProductDetail` class when calling `self.ids`.
2. Maybe the `name` is not actually a string datatype. Could check `type(name)`, and change to a string if necessary?
3. I've had issues with calling `self.ids` from other classes, so I prefer to use a `StringProperty`. I create a `StringProperty` in the class. In kv language, set the label text to the `StringProperty`, and in python change the `StringProperty` to the product name, and the kv language file will automatically update the label with whatever string the `StringProperty` holds. See added code and comments below.

python:

```
from kivy.uix.button import Button
from kivy.uix.image import Image
from kivy.uix.label import Label
from kivy.graphics import Color, Rectangle
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.core.window import Window
from kivy.uix.screenmanager import Screen
import database_handler
from kivy.lang import Builder
from kivy.uix.relativelayout import RelativeLayout
from kivy.uix.gridlayout import GridLayout
from kivy.clock import Clock
from globalstate import GlobalState
from kivy.properties import StringProperty 
# import the StringProperty

Builder.load_file('product.kv')

class ProductDetailScreen(Screen):
    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        super(ProductDetailScreen, self).__init__(**kwargs)

    def on_enter(self, *args):
        GlobalState.is_user_authenticated = True
        if not GlobalState.is_user_authenticated:
            self.manager.current = 'home'
            return

class ProductDetail(RelativeLayout):

    label_text = StringProperty('product name') 
    # create the StringProperty with first value

    def __init__(self, **kw):
        super().__init__(**kw)

    def get_value(self, id, *args):

        print("Recieve ID: ", id)
        result_data = database_handler.load_product_detail(id)

        for x in result_data:
            name = x[1]

        print("Fetched name:", name)

        self.label_text = name 
        # change the string property to the fetched value
```

kv language file:

```
<ProductDetail>:
    id: product_detail 
    # add an id so you can call the StringProperty from the class
    description: ''
    image: ''
    canvas:
        Color:
            rgba: 0.898039, 0.898039, 0.909804, 1
        Rectangle:
            pos: self.pos
            size: self.size
        
    Label:
        id: product_name
        text: product_detail.label_text
        # bind the label text to the StringProperty
        # you may also be able to bind with 'self.parent.label_text'
        font_family: 'Roboto'
        font_size: 45
        color: 0.482353, 0.552941, 0.576471, 1
        size_hint: (0.379688, 0.0541667)
        pos_hint: {'x':0.0484375, 'y':0.88125}
        text_size: 300, None
```

Comment: Thanks for answer. I check `name` is string. Use `StringProperty` is nothing change when I match with widget id.

Comment: I test to print data which is show on console is correct but when I sue to match with widget id is error.